# Fuseki server - unable to load dataset

Tags: jena, fuseki

I am using fuseki-server to query a large chunk of data. The data is in .nt format and I have stored it in a folder using tdbloader (The folder contains .dat and .idt files). Now when I try to load the data using:

```
./fuseki-server --loc="/path/to/database_folder/" /ds
```

I get an error message saying that the database I'm trying to load is locked by another process with PID = xxxxx and therefore can't be loaded. i have checked that no other instance of Fuseki-server is running on my system. Is there a way by which I can see which process is accessing that database folder and free it so that I can load it to the fuseki-server?

I also tried loading another .nt file the same way, by using tdb loader and finally setting its location to --loc and it works fine. The lock error appers only on the above dataset.

Comment: What OS are you running on? Stop the server; delete the lock file if and only if you are absolutely positive there is no other java program (not just fuseki) using the DB. (If there is, the DB will get corrupted.)

Comment: "spark" is nothing to do with "SPARQL". Tags removed.

Comment: @AndyS Deleting the lock file worked. Thanks!

Comment: deleting tdb.lock file inside the run/system/ helped